# Getting missing chunk in client module Using Webpack Module federation with CRACO

Tags: reactjs, webpack, code-splitting, webpack-module-federation, craco

`I am working on overhauling an existing React App to use a composite UI. I have opted to use the Module Federation plugin that Webpack provides. Instead of ejecting the webpack config that CRA makes I have decided to use CRACO to configure webpack.

I am able to start both the 'host' on port 3000 and 'client' on port 30001 separately, but when I try to load in the client into the host using lazy loading, I get a missing chunk error. The chunk does exist, but in the client on 3001, and it is looking in 3000. I am stuck on which configuration needs to be updated to look, or move the chunk to the right place.

Here is the output of the console for the error I get:

```
Loading chunk vendors-node_modules_react_jsx-dev-runtime_js failed.
(missing: http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_react_jsx-dev-runtime_js.chunk.js)
while loading "./App" from webpack/container/reference/MicroExample
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk vendors-node_modules_react_jsx-dev-runtime_js failed.
(missing: http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_react_jsx-dev-runtime_js.chunk.js)
while loading "./App" from webpack/container/reference/MicroExample
    at __webpack_require__.f.j (http://localhost:3001/moduleEntry.js:44353:29)
    at http://localhost:3001/moduleEntry.js:43512:40
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_require__.e (http://localhost:3001/moduleEntry.js:43511:67)
    at fn.e (http://localhost:3001/moduleEntry.js:43765:50)
    at ./App (http://localhost:3001/moduleEntry.js:43367:43)
    at get (http://localhost:3001/moduleEntry.js:43374:23)
    at handleFunction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:44010:31)
    at onInitialized (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:44022:73)
    at handleFunction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:44015:25)
```

client's craco.config.js:

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin')
const { dependencies } = require('./package.json')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    remote: './src/App',
  },
  configure: {
    output: {
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      path: '/',
    },
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3001,
    client: {
      overlay: true,
    },
  },
  webpack: {
    plugins: {
      add: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
          name: 'MicroExample',
          filename: 'moduleEntry.js',
          exposes: {
            './App': './src/App',
          },
          shared: {
            ...dependencies,
            react: {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: dependencies.react,
            },
            'react-dom': {
              singleton: true,
              eager: true,
              requiredVersion: dependencies['react-dom'],
            },
          },
        }),
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

Here is the 'host's craco.config.js:

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin')
const { dependencies } = require('./package.json')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      output: {
        publicPath: 'auto',
        path: '/',
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      add: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
          name: 'Host',
          remotes: {
            MicroExample: `MicroExample@http://localhost:3001/moduleEntry.js`,
          },
          shared: {
            ...dependencies,
            react: {
              eager: true,
              singleton: true,
              requiredVersion: dependencies.react,
            },
            'react-dom': {
              eager: true,
              singleton: true,
              requiredVersion: dependencies['react-dom'],
            },
          },
        }),
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

Here is the code I am using to lazy load the client:

```
const MicroUI = React.lazy(() =>
  import(
    'MicroExample/App' /* webpackChunkname: "microExample" */
  )
)

const SectionOverview = () => {

   return (
      <ErrorBoundary>
         <MicroUI/>
      </ErrorBoundary>
   )
}

export default SectionOverview
```

I have tried changing both of the publicPath's and path's in both configs to no avail. And have tried changing the path of the chunks around, but I have no idea if that is what I am supposed to do. There may be some CRA configuration that I cannot see that is causing this issue.`

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any solution for this issue?